# Replace ID number in Table A with string from Table B

Tags: mysql

Table A contains a list of prices for materials, one of the columns contains the material ID.

Table B contains the material ID and the material name as a string.

I'd like to include the material name from Table B where the material ID in table A matches.

I understand this would use some form of join but I'm new to SQL and unfamiliar with the syntax.

something like:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM prices 
    JOIN materials AS material_name ON prices.material = materials.id
```

I understand the above is incomplete and likely incorrect.

How can I pull in the value of the materials.name column where the prices.material and materials.id column match?

Comment: Do you want to actually _update_ the values in the `materials` table, or do you just want to generate a certain result set?

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its better to use left outer join in this type of problems.

```
SELECT a.material_id,b.material_name,a.price
From A a
LEFT JOIN B b
ON a.material_id=b.material_id;
```

Now change the columns you need in the SELECT statement according to your requirement.

Comment: `JOIN` without anything else before it (as in the OP) means `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: Using `INNER JOIN` means even a beginner that does not know that knows whats going on @stickybit

Comment: Because the OP is new to the syntax, you should probably explain why it's better with `LEFT` thant `INNER` (depending on the use, it could be not what is wanted)

Comment: @RiggsFolly: I don't get your comment. But as the answer was edited from suggesting an inner join (which the OP of the question already had, though not verbosely written) my comment and therefore your comment are obsolete anyway, I guess.

Comment: @stickybit Ok, I was not trying to pick a fight :) I just like code that self documents

Comment: @RiggsFolly: I'm not fighting too. Did your first comment try to tell, that using the verbose writing is better to understand whats going on? Then I'm with you. (But that wasn't the point of the original version of the answer at least as I understood it.)